# Electron for only front end

Tags: javascript, python, electron

I am trying to make my web application into a desktop app. I have already built and configured a server to host the backend scripting written in python.

My front end is written in JS, JQuery, HTML, CSS.

I have found an open source framework called Electron that packages web apps into desktop apps. Can I implement this so that it only wraps around my front end components without having to alter my back end server?

Comment: No there is no need to alter your back-end server because electron uses the same JS, HTML and CSS plus NodeJS.

Comment: So if I already have my app working in a browser, I should be good to go?

Comment: It seems to me you should rather explain _why_ you would like a desktop app made from your web app. There is no advantage, _except_ if you are counting on _offline_ usage, in which case you cannot rely on your back-end, or need to implement synchronisation, and you have to bake in more stuff in the desktop app for when your backend is unavailable (offline user). This is where electron can help you, and where you will have to provide extra effort beyond your web app.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, yes you can use your current web code to create a desktop app using Electron, as Electron in essence is basically just a simplified browser. However, you will need to add some things to your project if they don't already exist in order for Electron to work.

3 things in particular:

(See the quick start guide: https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)

1. package.json
2. main.js
3. index.html

You'll also need nodejs installed as electron itself is an npm module.

So not quite as straightforward as you may have thought but definitely a fairly simple and viable approach.